# How to handle main option with Getopt

Tags: perl, getopt

I want to handle a feature which seems to me almost natural with programs, and I don't know how to handle it with Getopt perl package (no matter Std ot Long).

I would like something like:

```
./perlscript <main option> [some options like -h or --output-file some_name]
```

Options will be handled with - or --, but I want to be able to let the user give me the main and needed option without dashes.

Is Getopt able to do that, or do I have to handle it by hand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds as though you are talking about non-options -- basic command-line arguments. They can be accessed with `@ARGV`. The `Getopt` modules will pass regular arguments through to your script unmolested:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

GetOptions (
    'foo'   => \my $foo,
    'bar=s' => \my $bar,
);

my @main_args = @ARGV;

# For example: perl script.pl --foo --bar XXX 1 2 3
# Produces:    foo=1  bar=XXX  main_args=1 2 3
print "foo=$foo  bar=$bar  main_args=@main_args\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have it written without a `-`, and it's also not optional (as you specifiy), then by any reasoning it isn't an *option* at all, but an *argument*. You should simply read yourself via

```
my $mainarg = shift
```

and then let Getopt do its thing. (You might want to check `$#ARGV` afterwards to verify that the main argument was actually given.)

Comment: That was I meant by handle it by hand.